# What's the best way #define macro Function used in linux and windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cross-platform

WindowsAPI functions currently used in the following examples for Linux

I want to use it as one definition depending on the platform.

`example.`

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
            ::CopyMemory(dest, readBuffer_ + fileOffset - readBufferOffset_, size);
#elif __linux__
            memcpy(dest, readBuffer_ + fileOffset - readBufferOffset_, size);
#endif
```

If there are a lot of processing like the above in the code, the readability is reduced.
So I want to use something like this, but I'm not sure what is a good way to do it.

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
  #define MEM_COPY CopyMemory
  #define SET_FILE_POINTER SetFilePointer
  #define READ_FILE ReadFile
#elif __linux
  #define MEM_COPY memcpy
  #define SET_FILE_POINTER lseek // parameter sequence not equal to SetFilePointer
  #define READ_FILE read
#endif


int main()
{
  // i wanna use one function (READ_FILE) both in linux and Windows
  READ_FILE(dest, readBuffer_ + fileOffset - readBufferOffset_, size);
}
```

I have an additional question.

Windows has many safety functions.

ex) fopen_s
memcpy_s

in linux
I've seen memcpy used frequently. How do you usually judge a standard that guarantees safety?
(Is it ok to just use it normally? I have the linux manual manpage,
I saw the `note` contents.)

Comment: Have you looked at what CopyMemory actually is? It's a macro that calls memcpy :)

Comment: [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) is a standard C++ function. It should be available everywhere. You don't need conditional compilation to use it.

Comment: Thanks.

I have confirmed that memcpy is used inside WINAPI.

Added SetFilePointer and lseek as examples.

Comment: A better way would be to abstract away the differences using classes and objects. Like using the C++ standard file-stream classes instead of low-level file-handling. And if you need to use it for other things, likes pipes or sockets, then create abstractions for them (unless you're using a framework which already have such abstractions). Macros are seldom the correct solution to any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an abstraction layer for that in a namespace:

```
namespace OperatingSystemFunctions
{
    static void CopyMemory(arguments)
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
            ::CopyMemory(dest, readBuffer_ + fileOffset - readBufferOffset_, size);
#elif __linux__
            memcpy(dest, readBuffer_ + fileOffset - readBufferOffset_, size);
#endif    
    }
}



int main()
{
    MyMemoryCopy::CopyMemory(...);
}
```

Of course the arguments needs to match for that approach.

Comment: static methods `static void CopyMemory(arguments)` only

Is there a problem with defining and using headers in the implementation part?

Comment: Maybe that was not clear from my answer. The new class can be in a new header and also the implementation could be in a new source file but that is up to your logical structure of the program

Comment: Thanks you `RoQuOTrix`  I am inspired by you.

Comment: There's no need for an extra class to contain a single static method, just use a free function.

Comment: thanks @MatteoItalia  :) 

Thanks for everyone's contribution.

Comment: Why is there a struct?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That is a good point in general because I would also define an interface of these classes to stub them with dependency injection for unit tests

Comment: @MatteoItalia The struct right now is unnecessary you are right! Coming from a C# background I always use classes and normally also interfaces for dependency injection